# Remove quotes from inbook reference title with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I use BibTeX and `biblatex` to create a bibliography. In my BibTeX database I define a `@inbook` reference with author, title, year and booktitle. Now the problem is that the reference is rendered as:

> Author (year): “Title”. In: BookTitle.

I need to remove the quotes around the title.

I already have a custom cite style file with some other definitions, but I did not find where to remove these quotes.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/39366

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The default definitions for this are in `biblatex.def`.  In your case, they are:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

So you can add the following to your own `.tex` file (or to a `biblatex.cfg`):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1}
```

The first removes the quotation marks from your citations; the second from the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InBook{entry1,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  booktitle =    {Main Title of Book},
  title =    {InBook Title without Quotation Marks},   
  publisher =    {The Publisher},
  date =     3000,
  location =     {CityPlace},
  pages =    {63--90},
}
@article{entry2,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title of Article},
  journal =      {Journal Title},   
  volume =       {50},
  number =       {3},
  date =     3000,
  pages =    {63--90},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1}

\begin{document}

\cite{entry1,entry2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly! (I cannot upvote you because of my low reputation)

Comment: @Nicholas -- glad it worked!