# Suppress quotes or other markup in \citetitle

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to extract the title from a bibtex file and use it in the main document text.  I'm using `\citetitle`, but this adds the title plus whatever markup is defined for the bibliography style I'm using.  How do I get the article title as-is, without anything attached?

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs_local.bib}
@Article{fubar,
  author =       {J. Doe},
  title =        {A fabulous finding},
  journal =  {Journal of Improbable Results},
  year =         2010,
  volume =   42,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs_local.bib}
\begin{document}%
Test: {\bfseries \sffamily \citetitle*{fubar}}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4mm}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The generated document (cropped):

[image: Compiled document]

The desired document would not affect layout of the References, but would show the text **A fabulous finding** in the main document without any quotes.

Do I need to define my own citation command to get this effect, or is there a more low-level way to extract information directly from bibtex fields?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94090/39366

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The formatting of `\citetitle` is done by the field formatting `citetitle`. You can change it in the following way:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
```

The star version is used to redefine `citetitle` for all entry types.

Comment: I think that there should be some formatting applied, e.g., using `\emph`. The problem I have is that it is, by default, not consistent.

Answer (score 14):

It's actually a way easier, just use `\citefield`

```
\citefield{my-referenc}{title}
```

Comment: You might want to add that this works because `\citefield` uses the generic format defined via `\DeclareFieldFormat{citefield}{#1}` (so no formatting is applied, everything comes out bare), while `\citetitle` uses the `citetitle` format that follows the definition of the `title` format (as explained in Marco Daniel's answer).

Comment: moewe: Thanks for an explanation, I wasn't aware of that. I just accidentally found this works. You're welcome to edit my post and provide the explanation.