# Inline citations with only author, title and year

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I would like to put a few reference inside a beamer presentation.  Adding a full fledge bibliography is certainly awkward but the output of the `\fullcite` command from the `biblatex` pacakge is too verbose.

I am looking for a command similar to `\fullcite` that would only insert  author, title and year

Some sort of MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \XXXcite{Kennedy01}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

with biblio.bib containing

```
@Article{Kennedy01,
  author =       {Kennedy, Marc C. and O'Hagan, Anthony},
  title =        {Bayesian calibration of computer models},
  journal =      {Journal of the royal statistical society: series b (statistical methodology)},
  year =         2001,
  volume =    63,
  number =    3,
  pages =     {425-464}}
```

and `\XXXcite` being the needed command similar to `\fullcite`.

I suppose that [Where can I find collections of bibliography styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles/35048#35048) could be used but I have only a very restricted understanding of the working of `biblatex`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient way to do this (I'm new to biblatex), but it works

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Kennedy01,
  author =       {Kennedy, Marc C. and O'Hagan, Anthony},
  title =        {Bayesian calibration of computer models},
  journal =      {Journal of the royal statistical society: series b (statistical methodology)},
  year =         2001,
  volume =    63,
  number =    3,
  pages =     {425-464}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\customcite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1}, \citeyear{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \customcite{Kennedy01}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How would one do this for placing citations as footnotes? (e.g. a replacement for \footcite)?

Comment: \newcommand{\customfootcite}[1]{\footnote{\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1}, \citeyear{#1}}}
worked! Thanks.

Comment: Just a warning that putting together several `\...cite` commands into one `\newcommand` is not best practice with `biblatex`. For one commands defined like this deal badly with multiple citation keys and don't support pre- and postnotes. Additionally, the fact that a work is passed to several `\...cite` commands can cause issues with citation tracking (e.g. "ibid.".) ...

Comment: ... It's usually *much* safer and better to define a new citation command with `\DeclareCiteCommand` as shown in Oleg's (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123145/35864) and user's (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511717/35864) answer.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the most straightforward way is to define a new citation command:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\customcite}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}%
      \indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
   \newunit
   \printfield{year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The same answer as [@Oleg Domanov](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24176) but also adding a hyperlink to the citation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
author = {Buthor, B.},
year = {2002},
title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\customcite}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}%
      \indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printnames{labelname}%
       \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
       \newunit
       \printfield{year}%
     }%
   }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

In this cite \customcite{A01} I do get a link now.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Related questions:

1. [What do \setunit and \newunit do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409148/what-do-setunit-and-newunit-do)
2. [Suppress quotes or other markup in \citetitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122665/suppress-quotes-or-other-markup-in-citetitle)
3. [Make \cite{my reference} show name and year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135649/make-citemy-reference-show-name-and-year)
4. [hyperlinking author names in biblatex when using \citeauthor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75902/hyperlinking-author-names-in-biblatex-when-using-citeauthor)
5. [biblatex+hyperref: citetitle/citeauthor and get hyperlink](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108344/biblatexhyperref-citetitle-citeauthor-and-get-hyperlink)
6. [Hanging references using \fullcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13272/hanging-references-using-fullcite)
7. [Using printfield of biblatex without formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426414/using-printfield-of-biblatex-without-formatting)
8. [How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207591/how-to-extract-bibtex-entries-as-doi-abstract-etc/207676#207676)
9. [Custom \cite command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473949/custom-cite-command?noredirect=1&lq=1)
10. [biblatex - How can I make \printfield{number} just print the number (figures) without "Nr."?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207827/biblatex-how-can-i-make-printfieldnumber-just-print-the-number-figures-wi)
11. [\citefield link to bibliography (hyperref & backref)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176052/citefield-link-to-bibliography-hyperref-backref)
12. [\citefield{key}{author} and \citefield{key}{journal} of biblatex do not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314491/citefieldkeyauthor-and-citefieldkeyjournal-of-biblatex-do-not-work)
13. [Alternative \citetitle command without italics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151970/alternative-citetitle-command-without-italics)
14. [Is bibtex unable to \cite specific entry (author, title) in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292573/is-bibtex-unable-to-cite-specific-entry-author-title-in-latex)
15. [How do I cite author in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69379/how-do-i-cite-author-in-latex)
16. [Cite title and author with one command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391158/cite-title-and-author-with-one-command)