# \citefield link to bibliography (hyperref & backref)

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, back-referencing

I would like to know if there is a way to get links and backref links on a \citefield command. For example, I want to cite only the title of a reference:

```
\citefield{ref}{title}
```

or any other field, and get the hyperlink to the reference and the corresponding backref link.

EDIT:

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
author = {Buthor, B.},
year = {2002},
title = {Bravo}, 
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{A01,B02}.

\newpage

In this cite \citefield{A01}{title} I do not get any link

\clearpage

Some more text \cite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is another approach on a lower level, I'll write it as another answer.

You also can patch the `\citefield`-command using the `xpatch`-package. Therefore you just have find its underlying macro which will be invoked by it: `\blx@cite@citefield`

You won't be able to use `\citefield{author}` as you wanted, because its internally not handled as a `field` but as a `name`, so you also had to patch `\citename`, if you want to use `\citename{key}{author}`. The third command in this row is `\citelist` which you also may have to patch. See `biblatex-manual, 3.7.7 Low-level Commands`.

My example contains patches for all three, but `\citename` and `\citelist` only in comments and untested. (It doesn't make much sense to me to use them in this way.)

If you really want to have ONE command like `\citeany{key}{field/name/list}`, I guess, you had to implement a new macro with an internal switch which leads to the macros `\citefield`, `\citekey`, `\citelist` depending on the given `field/name/list`. But this is rather more difficult, as you have to deal with the 5 optional parameters from the cite-commands. I don't know how to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{silence}\WarningFilter{latex}{Overwriting file}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
url = {http://www.something.com}
}
@misc{B02,
author = {Buthor, B.},
year = {2002},
title = {Bravo}, 
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\blx@cite@citefield}{\printfield[#4]{#5}}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[#4]{#5}}}{}{}%patch \citefield
% \xpatchcmd{\blx@cite@citename}{\printnames[#4]{#5}}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames[#4]{#5}}}{}{}%patch \citename
% \xpatchcmd{\blx@cite@citelist}{\printlist[#4]{#5}}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlist[#4]{#5}}}{}{}%patch \citelist


\begin{document}

Citefield A01 title: \citefield{A01}{title}.

\clearpage
Citefield B02 title: \citefield{B02}{title}.

Citefield A01 url: \citefield{A01}{url}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know a solution for `\citefield`.
But you can declare a new `citecommand` which will print out the specific wanted field. In the example below, I declare a new citecommand `\citetitle*` (I don't know how to overwrite `\citetitle`). Then you just have to wrap an `\printtext[bibhyperref]` around the output `\printfield...`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
author = {Buthor, B.},
year = {2002},
title = {Bravo}, 
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citetitle}%your new citecommand \citetitle*
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%like \citetile, 
    %only added \printtext[bibhyperref]{...} in this line
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

Some text \cite{A01,B02}.

\newpage

In this cite \citetitle*{A01} I do get a link now.

\clearpage

Some more text \cite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that with \citefield I do not get any link. No problems with \cite, \autocite, etc.

Comment: You're totally right. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was initially my idea, but since I want to print *any* field, I was wandering if there is any  general way of doing it with \citefield so I do not have to declare a cite command for every field I want to print/cite. Can \DeclareCiteCommand take an argument? Thank would be one possible solution, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: How do you print other details like author names, cite key (`[1]`), journal name etc?