# How do I display information from a BibTeX file in the main document?

Tags: tables, bibtex

I am trying to create a table with the information that is in my BibTeX file (like year of publication, description, etc) but I don't know how to do it.
For example, let say this is my BibTeX file:

```
@MISC{Test123,
  author = {t1},
  title  = {t2},
  year   = {t3}
}
```

And I want my LaTeX output to show a table that contains author, title, and year

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't want the full bibliography, just the author, title and year of each entry in the `.bib` file?

Comment: No, I want more information. The author, title, and year was just an example. I might want to show the description or the keywords that are on the bibtext

Comment: Forget BibTeX. Use Biblatex and Biber. If you are able to, that is.

Comment: It seems like you want to decide on a per-entry  which information shoud be included and which shouuld be omitted. If there is some sort of scheme, i.e. all books shall not print a publisher (for whatever reason) and all online entries shall omit the url, this would be programmable (with quite some effort).

Comment: If there is no scheme, using an automation tool is very pointless.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the direction. Using biblatex I was able to use \citefield{reference}{fieldname} and \citename{reference}{author} in the case of the author

Comment: @Yoiku `\citeauthor{<reference>}` would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. Thanks to @crf for mentioning Biblatex library

Here is a similar question with the answer and the example of code of how to do it

[\citefield link to bibliography (hyperref & backref)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176052/citefield-link-to-bibliography-hyperref-backref)