# Cite title and author with one command

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I often want to inline cite this way:

```
Please read the book "Title of my book" from Author.
```

or

```
Please read the book "Title of my book" (Author 2001).
```

Both requires to use two "cite" commands and therefore to cite twice.

```
 Please read the book \citetitle{A01} from \citeauthor{A01}
 Please read the book \citetitle{A01} \parencite{A01}
```

It bother me because I plan to make some statistics about citations (which author is the most cited, ...) and I suppose (I didn't look into this yet) it will create some problem.

`\textcite` is no better, it does not print title in my style (chicago). I cannot use `\fullcite` because it does not integrate with the text.

*Is there a way to cite the title and author (inline) with one command?*

MWE if needed:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  date = {2001},
  title = {An article title}},
  journaltitle = {A journal},
  number = {1},
  pages = {1--4},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

I encourage you to read the book \citetitle{A01} \parencite{A01}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not declare a new cite command? Then you just use the fields author and title.

Comment: Or declare something like `\newcommand*{\mycite}[1]{\citetitle{#1} from \citeauthor{#1}}` (though @TeXnician's way would be the preferred one).

Comment: @TeXnician I was guessing such a common usage where covered by Biblatex out of the bow. I am reluctant to create a new command because I export my text to html with pandoc and it will not recognized this customized command.

Comment: Well, `biblatex-chicago` is a author-date (or note) style, so it makes little sense to also define a 'title-"by"-author' and 'title (cite)' command as they would not conform to the normal use of citations with that style. You will have to define a new command, you can either do this from within `biblatex` (the preferred way) or by sticking together high-level commands (as suggested by Skillmon, this has disadvantages when it comes to pre- and postnotes, citation tracking and multiple citations).

Answer (score 8):

We can define two new cite commands `\ppracite` and `\pprbcite`.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\ppracite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\NewBibliographyString{pprby}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{pprby = {by}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\pprbcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \bibstring{pprby}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```