# Using printfield of biblatex without formatting

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex and I created my own citation to display some data from a bibliography entry in the way that I need. So far it works fine. However, the command `\printfield{<key>}` returns formatted text.

**Is there a way that I get the non-formatted text of the bibliography entry so I can format it as I want?**

In the example below, my citation prints the volume, the number and the doi of a given bibliography entry. But for the two elements, I get different formats (the two bibliographic entries have the same data but different type). For example (see the attached image) one prints `Volume: vol. 18` while the other print `Volume: 18`, or the `\printfield{doi}` command appends `DOI` at the beginning of the number.

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@Article{s18041198,
AUTHOR = {Olatinwo, Segun O. and Joubert, Trudi-H.},
TITLE = {Optimizing the Energy and Throughput of a Water-Quality Monitoring System},
JOURNAL = {Sensors},
VOLUME = {18},
YEAR = {2018},
NUMBER = {4},
URL = {http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/18/4/1198},
ISSN = {1424-8220},
DOI = {10.3390/s18041198}
}
@inproceedings{s18041197,
AUTHOR = {Olatinwo, Segun O. and Joubert, Trudi-H.},
TITLE = {Optimizing the Energy and Throughput of a Water-Quality Monitoring System},
JOURNAL = {Sensors},
VOLUME = {18},
YEAR = {2018},
NUMBER = {4},
URL = {http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/18/4/1198},
ISSN = {1424-8220},
DOI = {10.3390/s18041198}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycyte}
{}{
    Volume: \printfield{volume} \\
    Number: \printfield{number} \\
    DOI: \printfield{doi}
}
{}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \mycyte{s18041198}
    \item \mycyte{s18041197}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\thefield{...}`

Comment: In general the `number` and `volume` of an `@inproceedings` mean something else than that of `@article`. While I would buy that `volume` is kind of similar, `number` really means something else entirely for the different types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\thefield{...}` to access the raw data of a field. A similar command for name lists and literal lists does not exist.

You could use `\printfield[noformat]{<field>}` to print a field without additional formatting. But I think what you really want is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{myvolume}{\bibcplstring{volume}\addcolon\space#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{mynumber}{\bibcplstring{number}\addcolon\space#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{mydoi}{DOI\addcolon\space\nolinkurl{#1}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycyte}
  {}
  {\printfield[myvolume]{volume}%
   \setunit{\newline}%
   \printfield[mynumber]{number}%
   \setunit{\newline}%
   \printfield[mydoi]{doi}}
  {}
  {}
```