# Custom \cite command

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I'm trying to create a custom `\cite` command that takes in three arguments: the book/article name and the initial and final pages of the part that I'm citing. This is the code so far:

```
\renewcommand{\cite}[3]{
(vedi~\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{#3}}
{\parencite[\pno~#2]{#1}}
{\parencite[\ppno~#2~\hspace{-0.035cm}--\hspace{-0.035cm}~#3]{#1}}\hspace{0.035cm})\\}
```

So if the input is

```
\cite{book_1}{64}{64}
```

the output is

[image]

I'd like to modify is so that that output corresponds to the input

```
\cite{book_1, 64}
```

if the initial and final cited pages are the same, and

```
\cite{book_1, 64-65}
```

if they're different. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, rather than just use the optional arguments to the `\cite` command? e.g. `\cite[p.64]{book1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't think the usual input

> ```
> \autocite[64]{sigfridsson}
> \autocite[64-65]{sigfridsson}
> ```

is too complicated or far inferior to `\cite{key}{64}{65}`.

Here is a solution that only slightly modifies the macro `\mknormrange` to drop the second page number if it is equal to the first. We then need to change around the order of commands in the `postnote` formats to give expected output with respect to "p."/"pp.". Then you can use the standard `biblatex` postnote syntax

> ```
> \autocite[<startpage>-<endpage>]{<key>}
> ```

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange*[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange*[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange*[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@normrange@process#1#2{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{#2}
    {\blx@range@out@value{#1}}
    {\blx@range@out@value{#1\bibrangedash#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\autocite[64-64]{sigfridsson}

\autocite[64-65]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 64)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, pp. 64–65)]