# Comma-separated arguments for an adscript command

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

Is it possible to give the optional arguments in this command a comma-separated syntax, i.e. `\ads{A,1,2,3,4}` or `\ads{A}[1,2,3,4]`? (I think I'd prefer the first variant.) Despite reading [all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473965/a-command-challenge) [the](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378252/renewcommand-with-comma-separated-arguments) [relevant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303942/newcommand-with-comma-separated-argument-and-optional-arguments) [posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19693/arguments-of-custom-commands-as-comma-separated-list) [I](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19693/arguments-of-custom-commands-as-comma-separated-list?rq=1) [could](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87407/iterating-through-comma-separated-arguments?rq=1) [find](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378252/renewcommand-with-comma-separated-arguments?rq=1), I haven't so far managed to figure out to how to apply any of the approaches here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

% A command to apply adscripts to a base;
% the sequential definition of bases is to avoid spurious vspace from empty over-/under-sets;
% the ordering is anticlockwise from bottom.
\NewDocumentCommand{\ads}{o m o O{} O{} o}{%
    \ifx#1t\def\baseA{\text{#2}}\else\def\baseA{#2}\fi% define the base to be text, if desired
    \def\baseB{\baseA_{#3}^{#4}}% apply subscript and superscript
    \IfValueTF{#3}{\def\baseC{\underset{#3}{\baseB}}}{\def\baseC{\baseB}}% apply underset
    \IfValueTF{#6}{\def\baseD{\overset{#6}{\baseC}}}{\def\baseD{\baseC}}% apply overset
    \baseD%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\ads[t]{A}[1][2][3][4]
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost certainly this command can be shortened, but this is very quickly written and seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\newads@i#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6;{\def\myA{#1}\def\myB{#2}\def\myC{#3}\def\myD{#4}\def\myE{#5}}
\newcommand\newads[2][]{%
\expandafter\newads@i#2,,,,,;%
\def\baseB{\text{\myA}_{\myB}^{\myC}}%
\ifx\myD\empty
\def\baseC{\baseB}%
\else
\def\baseC{\underset{\myD}{\baseB}}%
\fi
\ifx\myE\empty
\def\baseD{\baseC}%
\else
\def\baseD{\overset{\myE}{\baseC}}%
\fi
\baseD}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\newads{A,1,2,3,4}\quad
\newads{A,,2,3,4}\quad
\newads{A,1,,,4}\quad
\newads{A,1,,\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]