# Alternative \citetitle command without italics

Tags: biblatex

How can I define a new command `\citetitleIdem` which behaves like `\citetitle` but not using italics? I am using biblatex with natbib.

I do not want to change the behaviour of `\citetitle`, therefore [this suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122665/suppress-quotes-or-other-markup-in-citetitle#122667) doesn't apply.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

One can use the `thefield` macro to paste the title. The following correspond to `\citetitle` and `\citetitle*`, but put the title without formatting such as italics:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitleIdem}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}{\thefield{title}}{\thefield{shorttitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitleIdem*}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\thefield{title}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```