# How can I have BibLaTeX's shorthand displayed without square brackets?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'd like to reference sources “in the flow in the text”, for example:

> As described in the User Manual, ...

Now, if I use the default BibLaTeX style (whichever it is), I get

> As described in the [User Manual], ...

or, using `\citetitle`

> As described in the *User Manual*, ...

How can I cite without either brackets or italics but *with* a prenote and the hyperlink?
Or maybe it's possible with `shorttitle`?

I would prefer a solution “out of the box”: using BibLaTeX's options or just switching the style, rather than writing some custom code for citations.

---

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[
backend = biber
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{biblio.bib}
@Online{key,
    author       = {author},
    title        = {title},
    shorthand    = {User Manual},
    shorttitle   = {User Manual}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[in the first half of the][]{key} % brackets

\textcite[in the first half of the][]{key} % not needed author

\citetitle[in the first half of the][]{key} % % no hyperlink, italic

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151970/alternative-citetitle-command-without-italics, I'm not sure if this is too much "custom code". For hyperlinks you could take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108344/biblatexhyperref-citetitle-citeauthor-and-get-hyperlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible solutions here. What is easiest depends on the context and on what else you would like to achieve.

If you don't select a style, `biblatex` defaults to `style=numeric,`. That explains the brackets you see everywhere: Numeric citations are usually given in brackets. And the `shorthand` is just treated as a replacement for the numeric label.

If you don't need numeric citations, you can choose a different style like `authortitle`, that does not come with brackets. `\printbibliography` will not print any labels/shorthands in that style, though, but if you want to see the `shorthand` in the bibliography section at the end you can use `\printshorthands`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authortitle,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{key,
    author       = {author},
    title        = {title},
    shorthand    = {User Manual},
    shorttitle   = {User Manual},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[in the first half of the][]{key}

\textcite[in the first half of the][]{key}

\citetitle[in the first half of the][]{key}

\printshorthands
\end{document}
```

[image: in the first half of the User Manual author (in the first half of the User Manual) in the first half of the User Manual]

---

An alternative solution if you stick with `style=numeric,` would be to tell `\cite` to lose the brackets.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{key,
    author       = {author},
    title        = {title},
    shorthand    = {User Manual},
    shorttitle   = {User Manual},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[in the first half of the][]{key}

\textcite[in the first half of the][]{key}

\citetitle[in the first half of the][]{key}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: in the first half of the User Manual author [in the first half of the User Manual] in the first half of the User Manual]