# biblatex: Inconsistent behavior of `citetitle` (quotation marks vs. italic)

Tags: biblatex

- **Observation:** It seems like the `\citetitle` command formats the title differently depending on the entry type.
- **MWE:** In the example below, an **article** is formatted as `"Title"` (I assume `\enquote{Title}`) and **report** is formatted as `\textit{Title}.`
- **Question:** **(1)** Is this intended? **(2)** Can I force (in a clean non-hacky way) the same formatting (I prefer `"Title"` or `\enquote{Title}`)?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

% See https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Article] \citetitle{baez/article} % @article{baez/article,
\item[(Tech)Report] \citetitle{padhye} % @report{padhye,
\end{description}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Related

- [Suppress quotes or other markup in \citetitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122665)
- [Remove quotes from inbook reference title with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94089)
- [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462133) (Thanks to user [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) for this reference.)

Comment: The `citetitle` field format mirrors the normal `title` field format, which is type-specific and formats titles of different types differently. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 for a more thorough discussion of the `title` field format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like the \citetitle command formats the title differently depending on the entry type.

Indeed. From there to the "inconsistent" in the title, it is a step though... I haven't done the setup, but to me it seems that it is different for each entry type precisely to be consistent with how the title is formatted elsewhere (bibliography, etc.).

But, as usual, with `biblatex` you can have it your way. The starred version of `\DeclareFieldFormat*` allows you to override all type-specific settings for a particular format:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Article] \citetitle{baez/article} % @article{baez/article,
\item[(Tech)Report] \citetitle{padhye} % @report{padhye,
\end{description}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: (1) Great, thanks! (2) What does `\isdot` do? (3) I will wait a bit to see if maybe user moewe will add an additional comment/answer. (4) I do not remember seeing you around, nice to meet you!

Comment: `\isdot` makes a period be interpreted as an abbreviation dot. It is used in `biblatex.def` for titles between quotes, thus I included it too, I presumed it is there to ensure a title with a final period is dealt with correctly. And nice to meet you too!