# Change appearance of "title" field for entries of type "@article"

Tags: biblatex

In this bibliography, the `title` field of an entry of type `@article` is encased in quotation marks, and `title` field of an entry of type `@book` is typeset in italics.

How can I change that the `title` field of an entry of type `@article` is also written in italics and without " "?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @Article{Aili2010,
      Title      = {Bioresponsive peptide-inorganic hybrid nanomaterials},
      Author     = {Aili, Daniel},
      Journal    = {Chem. Soc. Rev.},
      Year       = {2010},
      Volume     = {39},
   }
   @Book{Prodan2003,
      Title      = {A Hybridization Model for the Plasmon Response of Complex Nanostructures},
      Author     = {Prodan, E. and Radloff, C. and Halas, N. J. and Nordlander, P.},
      Year       = {2003},
   }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test.\cite{Prodan2003}\cite{Aili2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which style guide or manual requires this? In most cases, what you want is plain wrong.

Comment: Can you explain this? Why this is plain wrong?

Comment: I said in most cases. If you have been told to use a style which requires this, obviously it isn't wrong. But it would be interesting to know which style that is, because this would be wrong according to most of (all?) the styles I've seen and certainly all those I'm familiar with. Quotation marks aren't always used, but article titles are never italicised. Journal titles are italicised, but not article titles or titles of articles in anthologies or collections. Book, collection and journal titles get the italics.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the appearance of the `journal` field for entries of type `@article`? Should journal names continue to be typeset in italics?

Comment: @cfr -- Not that I in any way defend the style, but American law journals often put article titles in italics and the titles of books in small caps (or [also in italics](https://www.law.cornell.edu/citation/5-000#5-100)). Why? I've always assumed it is yet another example of (relatively blind adherence to) *stare decisis*....

Comment: Perhaps this answer (of mine) can be adapted to your goal: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94090/8528

Comment: @jon Thanks. Lawyers do seem to be a law unto themselves .... The italics vs. small-caps I can see - after all, how you mark things is just arbitrary - but to put everything in italics seems unhelpful to me.

Comment: Building on jon's answer you could use `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` or just `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`. Or to make all titles emph-ed: `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`

Comment: Yes, thank you. But what can I do if a title is set in italics and I want it to get straight?

Comment: Well, you need to find out which format it is and change that to `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}` (`\mkbibquote{#1}` is for quotation marks, `\mkbibemph{#1}` for emphasis/italics, and `#1` for plain upright font).