# How to remove quotation marks from "title" field, ieeetr bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using the `natbib` citation management package and the `ieeetr` bibliography style for my references. Everything works well apart from the quotation marks that are placed around the `title` fields of all entries. How can I remove these quotation marks? I saw a similar post for biblatex:

[Remove quotes from inbook reference title with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94089/remove-quotes-from-inbook-reference-title-with-biblatex)

I tried to do the same in the `natbib.def` file but it did not work. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Dear Mico,Yes, that's right. I am modifying the ieeetr.bst file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bibliography style -- here: `ieetr`-- and not the chosen citation management package (such as `natbib`) determines virtually all aspects of how bibliographic entries, including the placement of quotation marks around the contents of `title` fields, are formatted by BibTeX.

You could proceed as follows to achieve your objective:

- Find the file `ieeetr.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `ieeetr-noquotes.bst`. Do *not* edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `ieeetr-noquotes.bst` in your favorite text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Inside the bst file, locate the functions `format.title` and `format.title.p`. (In my copy of the file, the code begins on line 250).

  The code block should look like this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.title}
  { title empty$
      { "" }
      { "``" title "t" change.case$ * ",''" * }
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {format.title.p}
  { title empty$
      { "" }
      { "``" title "t" change.case$ * ".''" * }
    if$
  }
  ```

  Aside: In the `ieeetr` bibliography style, the function `format.title` is used to format the contents of the `title` field for most entry types -- except `@booklet`, `@misc`, and `@unpublished`, for which `format.title.p` is used under certain circumstances. (Feel free to parse the code in the function `misc` to explore these "certain circumstances"...)
- Change the lines before the respective `if$` statements to

  ```
      { "" title "t" change.case$ * "," * }
  ```

  and

  ```
      { "" title "t" change.case$ * "." * }
  ```
- Save the file `ieeetr-noquotes.bst` -- either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystlye{ieeetr}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystlye{ieeetr-noquotes}
  ```
- Finally, run a complete recompile cycle -- latex, bibtex, and latex twice more -- to fully propagate the resulting changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

A full MWE that uses the modified form of the `ieeetr` bibliography style:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{abc,
   author  = "Anne Author",
   title   = "Thoughts",
   journal = "Circularity Today",
   year    = 3001,
   volume  = 1,
   number  = 2,
   pages   = "3-4",
}
@unpublished{def,
   author  = "Zebulon Zwicki",
   title   = "Further Thoughts",
   note    = "Private Communication",
   year    = 3002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr-noquotes}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Just for completeness, here's how the output of the preceding MWE looks like if the unmodified `ieeetr` bibliography style were used:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to upvote but I am not allowed to because I don't have any reputation. How do I accept?

Comment: OK, I found it :)