# Using biblatex with EasyChair document class

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a paper with the EasyChair [document class](http://www.easychair.org/publications/for_authors), and I want to use `biblatex` obtaining the same bibliography style.

The only thing the document class does to the bibliography is to make the font `\small` and adjust some lengths. The corresponding code from `easychair.cls` is the following:

```
% Tighten up bibliography
\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\endoldthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
{
    \small
    \begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}
        \setlength{\parskip}{2pt}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
}
{
    \end{oldthebibliography}
}
```

If I load `biblatex` these changes are overwritten and I get the default size for the bibliography entries. I know absolutely nothing about how to customize `biblatex` bibliographies.

Also, for some reasons the titles of the bibliography entries are enclosed in single quotes with `biblatex` while they are not with `bibtex`.

How to create an 'easychair' bibliography style for biblatex with the same customizations?

Comment: If could add an MWE, we can test our suggestions more thoroughly.

Comment: The issue about the quotation marks should be a new question and there we should really have to see an MWE. But note that if you use a `biblatex` style that will probably not give the same result as one of your old `.bst` files gave, so differences are to be expected.

Comment: Ok, I'll give you an MWE as soon as possible in another question. Anyway, once adjusted `\bibitemsep` and `\biblabelsep` I don't see differences other than the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the font size to small with

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
```

see [How to change font size for bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1441/35864)

The default is `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}`, but you can set

```
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0pt}
```

explicitly. This gives you what the `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` did in your old code.

Comment: What about the `\parskip` setting? Is there `\bibparskip` as well?

Comment: Nope, there is not. You'll hardly ever have a parskip in your bibliography anyway, so if you don't notice anything in your document, I'd let it go. You could of course try `\AtBeginBibliography{\setlength{\parskip}{2pt}}`

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot add an MWE right now, I'll try as soon as possible. Anyway, your suggestions worked for the font, but there is still the `\parskip` length to set. It seems it changes the distance between the numbers [1], [2] ecc.. and the bib items themselves. Unfortunately I noticed another difference, that the title of the cited works are enclosed by single quotes. I've edited the question.

Comment: I've tried the `\AtBeginBibliography` but the distance between numbers and bib items doesn't change. Maybe it isn't `\parskip` that changes that.

Comment: @gigabytes Indeed, the distance between the number and label should be `\biblabelsep`. The default is`\setlength{\biblabelsep}{2\labelsep}`, you can make that smaller to `\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}`, the radical `\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}` looked weird to me.

Comment: yeah, now it is perfect apart from the quotes. How to tell `biblatex` not to put the titles in quotes?

Comment: @gigabytes As I said, the quotation mark issue should really be a new question. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94089/35864 though, maybe that or `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}` can help.